# Java MongoDB Driver Position of a Document for a Ranking

Tags: java, mongodb, driver, ranking

My problem is the following, I do not know how to get the position of a document, the whole is for a ranking. The documents are structured as follows: Name (Example), Kills (10). Sorted according to the kills

MongoDB Driver version is 3.4.2

Please help me!

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying something like sorting your Collection by kills and then get the rank of a player.

So you pretty much need to iterate through the sorted FindIterable until you find the name you're looking for:

```
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = ...; //your collection
    int i = 1;
    for (Document doc : collection.find().sort(Sorts.descending("kills"))) {
        if (doc.getString("name").equals(/*THE NAME YOU'RE SEARCHING FOR*/)) {
             //i is the "rank"
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Hope I got your question right :P